# React infinite loop when using useffect with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm setting a radux state with an object, the get the value from the store and print it on screen

I'm using `useState` and use `useEffect`

```
const AvatarContainer = (props) => {
const [infos, setinfos] = useState(undefined);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in effects')

    setinfos(() => props.userInfos)

}, [props.userInfos]);
 
props.saveUserInfos(authContext.getCachedUser())

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return ({
        userInfos: state.reportingActions.userInfos,
    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return ({
        saveUserInfos: (Avatar) => dispatch(saveUserInfos(Avatar))
    })
}
```

**reducer**

```
case 'SAVE_USER_INFOS':
   return {
       ...state,
       userInfos: Object.assign({}, action.payload.userInfos
   }
```

**action**

```
export const saveUserInfos = userInfos => {

    return ({
        type: 'SAVE_USER_INFOS',
        payload: {
            userInfos
        }
    })
}
```

I get this error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call redux action in useEffect, like below,

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect done")
    if (photo === undefined) {
        setinfos(props.userInfos)
    }
    props.saveUserInfos(authContext.getCachedUser())
}, []);
```

Your code goes in infinite loop because `props.saveUserInfos(authContext.getCachedUser())` update your component props and when your component's props is update then it will be remount or re-render again

Hope this answer helps you!

Answer (score 0):

`props.saveUserInfos(authContext.getCachedUser())` is executed each time the component re-renders. It triggers a redux action dispatch that manipulates redux store which in turn triggers re-render of AvatarContainer component. Then, `saveUserInfos` is executed so the process repeats and effectively enters infinite loop.

To resolve your issue you need to change the logic when the actual save is done. A starting point - depending on what you want to achieve - might be to move into into effect that triggers on internal state change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.saveUserInfos(authContext.getCachedUser())
, [infos]);
```

This way, external store's state will be synchronized each time internal state changes.